# tf-idf in multi-label classification task

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I have a question regarding application of [tf-idf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf).

Let's assume I have a [document classification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_classification) task, there is a training set of documents that are multi-labeled, such that one document can have multiple labels. I use bigrams and unigrams as a features and tf-idf as features values.

The question is, how to calculate td-idf values.

For example I have **document 1** that classified as **class1** and **class2**.

**tf** should be just the frequency of feature **f** in **document 1** or frequency of feature **f** in all documents of type **class1** and **class2** or frequency of feature **f** in the entire corpus?

The same question regarding **idf**. Should I consider the class of dicument when calculating it?

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't have to consider the document class when calculating IDF. TF.IDF can be used completely independent of the class labels.

In other words the TF term is just the frequency of a particular unigram/bigram *in the document*. The IDF is the inverse of the frequency of a particular unigram/bigram in the *whole* corpus.